# kerberos configuration for spring xd kafka source

Tags: spring-xd

I am trying to connect to kafka through spring xd kafka source.
I need to configure the Kerberos and TLS.
My Requirement is to enable Kerberos and also give client.properties like below to consumer.

```
ssl.keystore.location=/var/private/ssl/sdp.cloud.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=abc123
ssl.key.password=abc123
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/sdp.cloud.keystore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=abc123
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
group.id=testgroup
```

The sample provided by kafka is like below:
kafka-console-consumer --new-consumer --bootstrap-server servers --topic test --from-beginning --consumer.config /etc/kafka/client.properties

--Updated

How can i give above mentioned properties to kafka source module?

Comment: And what is the issue that you have?

Comment: How can i give above mentioned properties to kafka source module?

Comment: Maharshi, were you able to enable kerberos on springXD. Please provide me the steps to configure kerberos for kafka